# Visited Links in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building my first site and I am having trouble with the coloration of visited links. They currently turn purple after they've been visited. How do I change this function? Here is my current code:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: none; 
}
```

Comment: What about `color` ?

Comment: If you set a `color` you can override the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the default behavior of changing the color into purple you have to override the `a:visited` color as following.

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Visited</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion already made, something like:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: none; 
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#"> Link </a>
```